# IAM getting stuck with SIGSEGV runtime error in codechef when i submit my code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

**This is my code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
long int a[100001],b[100001];
int main()
{
long int n=0,m=0,bp=0,bn=0,i=0,x=0,Result=0;//declaration
char ch='\0';
FILE *fp;
scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&m);
fp=fopen("array.txt","w");//file reading
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    ch=getchar();
    fputc(ch,fp);
}
fclose(fp);
fp=fopen("array.txt","r");//file scaning to array
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%1d",&a[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
while(m>0)
{
    scanf("%ld",&x);
    bp=0;
    bn=0;
    for(i=0;i<x-1;i++)
    {
        b[i]=a[x-1]-a[i];
        if(b[i]>0)
            bp = bp+b[i];
        else
            bn = bn+b[i];
    }
    Result=bp-bn;
    printf("%ld\n",Result);
    m--;
}
return (0);
}
```

when i run this code in my system it is giving correct output but in codechef it is showing SIGSEGV runtime error... please help me to write a efficient program
the linkto problem is http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/ADIGIT

Comment: You have no error checking on the calls to fopen - how do you even know the file was created successfully ?

Comment: Why does the comment say "file reading" when you open the file for writing? Misleading comments are worse than no comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to open file for reading/writing on Codechef. That is why you are getting SIGSEGV.

I don't understand the need to do file I/O for the problem.

**Also, you should delete the code, because this is a problem from running contest.**